# How to set Outlook From email address from Word VBA

Tags: vba, outlook, ms-word, email

I'm trying to use Word VBA to send a document to an email recipient. For the most part, it is not difficult. I have this code so far:

```
With oItem
    'Set the recipient for the new email
    .To = "person1@mail.com"
    'Set the recipient for a copy
    .CC = "ccperson@mail.com"
    'Set the subject
    .Subject = "Blah blah"
End With
```

My problem is that I have several sender email addresses configured in Outlook, and Outlook is picking the wrong one by default.

Is there a way to specify a sender email address using the method above? Needless to say, the intuitive code line for specifying a sender address (`.From = me@wherever.com`) does not work. Thank you.

UPDATE:

I finally got my code to work after modifying it using the suggestions from peakpeak and Dimitry below. My changes were

1) to include a reference to the Microsoft Outlook 16 object library so that I could get access to the `Outlook.MailItem` datatype. The mail would send fine with the code above (without the reference), but would always send with the wrong From address.

2) Declare the mail item as `Outlook.MailItem`. This seemed to enable the `SentOnBehalfOfName` field.

3) Used my desired From: email address in the `SentOnBehalfOfName` field.

Here is the working code:

```
Dim MAPIMailItem As Outlook.MailItem
Set MAPIMailItem = olkApp.CreateItem(olMailItem)  'Create a new mail message
With MAPIMailItem
    .BodyFormat = olFormatPlain
    .to = strTo

   ' SentOnBehalfOfName sets the From field on my machine,
   ' AFTER I declared MAPIMailItem as Outlook.MailItem
    .SentOnBehalfOfName = "fromAddress@foo.com"

    .Subject = strSubject
    .body = strBody
    .attachments.Add strAtt
   '.send
    .Display
End With
```

Comment: you need to set this property `.SentOnBehalfOfName`

Comment: Thank you for your reply, but ... that doesn't change the From: address that shows in my Outlook message window that pops up. It's like creating an Outlook mail item always creates the item with the default sender address already in place...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use this code:

```
Dim WantedAccount as String ' Set to preferred account name
Set MAPISession = objOutlook.Application.Session     'Get the MAPI Outlook session

Set MAPIMailItem = objOutlook.CreateItem(olMailItem)  'Create a new mail message
With MAPIMailItem
  For Each Account In MAPISession.Accounts
    If Account = WantedAccount Then
      .SendUsingAccount = Account
      Exit For
    End If
  Next
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. I'm trying to figure out the data types of ```MAPISession``` and ```MAPIMailItem``` so that I can get Intellisense to work. But I can't find those objects in the Word VBA Object inspector... Could you point me to the correct definitions somewhere? (I ran your code and it correctly cycles through my mail accounts, but Intellisense doesn't show me the fields like ```.SendUsingAccount``` etc.)

Comment: also, after I get the right account using your code, setting the ```SendUsingAccount``` field does not make a difference. Outlook still pops up an email containing the wrong From address...

Comment: I finally got it working after adding a reference to the Outlook 16 object library and using the ```SentOnBehalfOfName``` property. Yay! See the update in the original post for working code. The answer was a combination of peakpeak and Dimitry's contribution (and I suppose, mine), but I can only mark one as an answer...

Answer (score 2):

If you are sending through an Exchange account, set the `MailItem.SentOnBehalfOfName` property (assuming you have the right to send on behalf of the specified mailbox). If you are sending through a POP3/SMTP account, set the `MailItem.SendUsingAccount` property.

Comment: Hi Dimitry, sorry to say but neither one of those fields seems to work with my code for some reason. Outlook still pops up the email with the wrong account loaded in the From field...